# module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.1.6

Tags: scala, sbt

I installed SBT via terminal with following commands:

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

on my Ubuntu 18.04 and with java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

The installation was successful but when I tried to start `SBT` via terminal, then I've got

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6/ivys/ivy.xml

```
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.1.6: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6/sbt-1.1.6.pom

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6/sbt-1.1.6.jar

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6/sbt-1.1.6.pom

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6/sbt-1.1.6.jar

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6/sbt-1.1.6.pom

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6/sbt-1.1.6.jar

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6/ivys/ivy.xml

    Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.1.6/ivys/ivy.xml
```

What is wrong?

**Update**

```
developer@monad:~$ sudo apt-get purge openjdk-8-jdk java-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-11-jre-headless : Depends: ca-certificates-java but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: java-common (>= 0.28) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

List of installed java version:

```
developer@monad:~$ update-java-alternatives --list
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1101       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

**Update 2**

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-java
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ca-certificates-java is already the newest version (20170930ubuntu1).
ca-certificates-java set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libice-dev libsm-dev libxt-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: you need to point SCALA_HOME to the scala installation directory too

Answer (score 9):

The root cause is a conflict between openjdk-11-jdk (which is default in Ubuntu 18.04) and sbt packages settings. It has already been fixed in Debian and will be included in Ubuntu shortly. Meanwhile the simplest workaround is to demote your java to version 8. Other solutions employing `ca-certificates-java` are much more complicated.

First remove conflicting packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk* java-common default-jdk
sudo apt-get remove --purge sbt
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Check weather you successfully removed all related packages by:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

The system shall prompt you **there is no Java available to config**, otherwise this workaround **fails**.

Then reinstall required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk sbt
```

Test by:

```
sbt compile
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem is java-certificates so you need to run these commands:

## Reinstall JDK

```
$ sudo apt-get purge openjdk-8-jdk java-common
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

## Run sbt

```
$ sbt
```

Comment: Did you install `ca-certificates-java`?

Comment: How to install `ca-certificates-java`?

Comment: `sudo apt install ca-certificates-java`

Comment: yes. `run sbt` does not work. It says it can not find the commend.

Comment: I had the exact problem yesterday. And these commands help me. I also use ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172213/discussion-between-zero-coding-and-metmirr).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you install Java/Scala/SBT totally independent from the OS packages. It does not matter (or should not matter!) for a developer which specific version of Java was installed by `apt-get`, `yum` or whatever.

From the developer's perspective, it may even make sense to test your application under several versions of Java. I've seen this situation before: "it works" under Java 1.8.x but "it fails" under Java 1.8.y.

So, from a developers, perspective, you would be interested on quickly swithing versions of Java, so that you can quickly make sure it works properly under those several different versions, no matter which specific version is installed on your specific version of the OS.

If you liked the idea, this is how it works:

1. Download manually all JDK versions you like and uncompress them under a given folder under your home folder, say: `$HOME/tools`. I have a script which automagically installs a certain version of the JDK for you: https://github.com/frgomes/bash-scripts/blob/master/scripts/user-install/install-java.sh
2. Adjust environment variables in a `virtualenv`-like fashion. It's easier than you think and you dont't even need `virtualenv`. All you need is to `source` a shell script which runs at login time which defines `JAVA_HOME`, pointing to a given version of Java, under your `$HOME/tools`. This is an example: https://github.com/frgomes/bash-scripts/blob/master/bashrc-virtualenvs/j8s12/bin/postactivate
3. Install Scala and SBT versions by hand, or using my automated script at https://github.com/frgomes/bash-scripts/blob/master/scripts/user-install/install-scala.sh

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me.

```
sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it by removing `.m2`, `.ivy` & `.sbt`.
Next time I executed `sbt`, it fixed everything.

I believe I broke sbt when I was playing with the cached dependencies or something else.